# How to access the typed-memory view element of a class declared in cython?

Tags: cython, python-3.5, typed-memory-views

I am a beginner and I am sure this question is too simple. I am trying to test memory views in cython to get to know them much better.In my code I pass each memory view element (like `[1,2]`) as the `cy` class element `move`.

```
cdef class cy:
    cdef public long[:] move
    def __init__(self, move):
        self.move = move
lst = []
for i in range(100):
    lst.append([i, i+1])

cdef long[:, :] memview = np.asarray(lst)

b0 = cy(memview[0])
print(b0.move)
```

When I print the results. I get this:

```
<MemoryView of 'ndarray' object> # I expect for sth like [12, 13]
```

I need `cy` class prints out a list. How can I fix it?
there is another problem which occurs to me when I use this code:

```
cdef class parent:
    cdef public:
        list children
        list moves
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = []
    def add_children(self, moves):
        cdef int i = 0
        cdef int N = len(moves)
        for i in range(N):
            self.children.append(cy(moves[i]))

cdef int[:, :] moves = np.asarray(lst, dtype=np.int32)
obj = parent()

for move in moves:
    obj.add_children(move)
```

After running this code I always get this error: 
`TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'int'`.
What causes this error and how can I fix this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first issue is just that a memoryview doesn't have a useful `__str__` function for print to use. You can either convert it to an object that does print nicely

```
print(list(b0.moves))
print(np.asarray(b0.moves))
```

Or you can iterate through it yourself:

```
for i in range(b0.moves.shape[0]):
    print(b0.moves[i], end=' ') # need to have Cython set to use Python 3 syntax for this line
print()
```

---

Your second problem is harder to solve since you don't tell us what line the error comes from. I think it's the constructor of `cy` which expects a memoryview but you pass an integer to. (I get a slightly different error message though).